# How to convert json to a fetch function in react

Tags: json, reactjs, post, fetch

the parameter with attribute named file is required and the actual curl command is:- curl -F "file=@password.txt" https://safenote.co/api/file -F password=secret -F lifetime=72 and the corresponding json format is:-

```
{
    "url": "https://safenote.co/api/file",
    "raw_url": "https://safenote.co/api/file",
    "method": "post",
    "files": {
        "file": "password.txt"
    },
    "data": {
        "password": "secret",
        "lifetime": "72"
    }
}
```

I need this to be converted into a fetch function or using axios, I'm not understanding which is the body part ad what to include
I have tried :-

```
 fetch(`https://safenote.co/api/file`,{
                mode:'no-cors',
                method:"POST",
                // headers: {
                //      "Content-Type": "application/json"
                // },
                "files":{
                    "file":selectedFile,
                },

                // body: JSON.stringify({
                // file:selectedFile
            })
            // })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log("data",data))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
```

my HTML part

````
  <input type="file" name="attachment" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" onChange={(e) => setSelectedFile(e.target.files[0])}/>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use axios and form data for that

```
const myFormData = new FormData();

myFormData.append('files', 'file');
```

You can add another properties like name or whatever too

```
myFormData.append('name', 'myFileName');
```

then use the axios

```
axios({
  method: "post",
  url: "myurl",
  data: myFormData,
  headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
})
  .then(function (response) {
    //handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (response) {
    //handle error
    console.log(response);
  });
```

Comment: axios is a simple and easy approach. :)